# Webrtc how I can make the onicecandidate work on my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrtc

Hello guys I am very new in this webrtc and javascript I try get done a video stream but in my code the onicecandidate is never been call can some one help me where I make mistake

```
 $('body #call').on('click', function () {
            let receiverid = $(this).attr('data-ids');
            const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
                localStream = stream;
                localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
                    peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
                    localVideo.srcObject = localStream;
                });

            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            peerConnection.createOffer()
                .then(sdp => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp))
                .then(function () {
                    console.log('is emitedd offer');
                    socket.emit('onOffer', { callerid: userid, receiverid, offer: peerConnection.localDescription });
                });
            peerConnection.ontrack  = event => handleRemoteStreamAdded(event.streams[0], userid);

            peerConnection.onicecandidate = function(event) {
                if (event.candidate) {
                    console.log('emit candidate');
                  socket.emit('candidate', id, event.candidate);
                }
              };
        });
    });
```

Thanks so mush

Answer (score 1):

well I see better some example my error was I call the `peerConnection.createOffer()` offsite from my video object  `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => { // create offer here });` them My candidate start emited